# Recorrer linea por linea archivo txt, y mostrarlo en un label, windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Este es mi `Form`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `Label` tiene como nombre, `label1` y el botón como `button1`.

En el código del botón estoy poniendo esto:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string v= "";
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\JR\\Desktop\\TXTS\\ejemplo.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.

                v += "\t" + line;
            }
             label1.Text = (v);

        }
```

Al presionar, si esta leyendo el `txt`, pero me lo muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando mi txt esta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el resultado deberian salirme 5 lineas con el texto

Como le puedo hacer para que no salga todo pegado y salgan las 5 lineas?

Comment: En lugar de v += "\t" + line; prueba con v += Enviroment.NewLine + line;

Comment: Me salta este error: does not exits in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas usando la cadena de escape incorrecta.

En C# las cadenas de escape son las siguientes:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Scape      |                                                         ..                                                          |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| \'             | comilla simple, necesaria para caracteres literales.                                                                |
| \"             | comilla doble, necesaria para string literales.                                                                     |
| \\             | barra invertida                                                                                                     |
| \0             | caracter unicode 0                                                                                                  |
| \a             | Campana (caracter 7)                                                                                                |
| \b             | Retroceso (character 8)                                                                                             |
| \f             | Avance de página (character 12)                                                                                     |
| \n             | Nueva línea (caracter 10)                                                                                           |
| \r             | Retorno de carro (character 13)                                                                                     |
| \t             | Tabulación horizontal (character 9)                                                                                 |
| \v             | Tabulación vertical (character 11)                                                                                  |
| \uxxxx         | Secuencia de escape Unicode para caracteres con valor hexadecimal xxxx                                              |
| \xn[n][n][n]   | Secuencia de escape de Unicode para caracteres con valor hexadecimal nnnn (versión de longitud variable de \ uxxxx) |
| \Uxxxxxxxx     | Secuencia de escape Unicode para caracteres con valor hexadecimal xxxxxxxx (para generar sustitutos)                |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[Fuente](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/) y use [esta otra fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=vs-2019) para determinar el nombre en español de las cadenas de escape.

Ya sabiendo esto, podemos saber, que tu error se da porque `\t` no es un salto de línea, sino una tabulación.

Para realizar un salto de línea deberías usar `\n` o `Enviroment.NewLine`

Por lo que

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string v= "";
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\JR\\Desktop\\TXTS\\ejemplo.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.

                v += "\n" + line;
            }
             label1.Text = (v);

        }
```

Debería producir el resultado que buscas.

Comment: Si alguien piensa que es errónea la traducción del nombre de alguna de las cadenas de escape, edite la respuesta con toda confianza.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria uses

```
string path = @"C:\\Users\\JR\\Desktop\\TXTS\\ejemplo.txt";

string v = File.ReadAllText(path);

label1.Text = v;
```

de esta forma del archivo vas a recuperar los saltos de linea